# Ethanol / Methanol : Prison Hooch

Tags: alcohol

After speaking with a friend about home brew he told me a story about making prison hooch ( at home for a laugh ), strained through a sock etc. It's hilarious.

However when I talked about my plans to experiment with ingredients in my brews he told me that when he made his hooch he used a test strip or something to check if his beautiful brew in a bin bag had produced ethanol or the rather more deadly METHANOL!

I was mortified at the prospect of poisoning my friends with experimental ingredients.

So I'd like to ask;

Is there a chance I can add ingredients to my brew and inadvertently produce methanol?

Do I need to worry about this?

What would be a bad ingredient that could do this?

Should I use test strips for such bad alcohols?

Comment: Test strips for ethanol vs. methanol??? I don't think they exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beer made from barley malt will contain almost no methanol. [Fruits high in pectin will produce some methanol](http://homedistiller.org/intro/methanol/methanol), but it's only a health concern if you're distilling. (That being said, I've had some nasty hangovers after drinking plum wine.)

I've never heard of a test strip to determine the methanol quantity of a liquid. If such a thing existed, the home distilling community would be all over it.